# size breaker and wire to used on a car lift

Tags: electrical

Can someone tell me the breaker size and wire size to use on this car lift?

Here is a picture of the data plate:

[image]

Comment: Can you get us another photo of the dataplate that's more legible please?

Comment: does that say `290` volts?

Comment: @jsotola - Probably 230 volts.

Answer (score 4):

15A/14AWG would suffice,  but you'll get more general usefulness out of the circuit if you run 12 AWG.

Also, in many commercial locations, 12 AWG is the minimum allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You will need 15A 2 pole breaker and feed 240V to it. Run 14-2 and connect both black and white wires to 2 pole breaker. Mark white wire hot with a electric tape (or any other means).

Comment: I doubt you'd be running NM-14 cable to this.  Probably FMC with #12 AWG

Comment: The label says 11A, unless I'm reading it wrong. There is no harm done using 12 AWG though.  You are allowed to install larger breaker than the wire is rated for on motor loads as they have high starting current and exact size may cause breaker to trip on start up. I don't remember the exact rule though.

Comment: I was referring more to the Romex, NM cable, you mentioned running, 14-2.  Plus, I think 12 AWG  is minimum size for commercial.

Answer (score 1):

VBM was bought by Challenger. The 21000 uses the same [power unit](http://www.mcgeecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/vbm-lifts.pdf) as the 27000/31000.

The [Installation Instructions](http://www.mcgeecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/31000.pdf) for the 27000/31000 on page 17 says 25 amp two pole breaker, which would require minimum #10 AWG wire.

Comment: That is for 27000 and 31000. Can't see the full model # in the picture, but it clearly starts with 21, not 27 or 31.

Comment: I'd normally agree with Jack about 12ga FMC, but @NoSparksPlease gave a complete answer with manufacturer documentation to back it up. I'll agree with NoSparks, and recommend putting the wire in metal conduit for physical protection.